# Handling Null values from related entity

Tags: linq

I want to set default value if no matching result in found from related entity.

I am trying to display all values from first entity but two values from second table, any one value or both the values can be null in second table. Here is my query

```
var employeelist = _context.TblEmployee.ToList();

    foreach (var employee in employeelist)
    {               
        var employeeAtt = _context.AttendanceTable

            .GroupBy(a => a.DateAndTime.Date)
                .Select(g => new EmployeeAtt
                {
                    Date = g.Key,
                    Emp_name = employee.EmployeeName,
                    InTime = g.Where(e => e.ScanType == "I").Min(e => e.DateAndTime.TimeOfDay),
                    OutTime = g.Where(e => e.ScanType == "O").Max(e => e.DateAndTime.TimeOfDay),

                });
        empWithDate.AddRange(employeeAtt);
    }
```

I want InTime and OutTime to Store "Absent" if there value is `NULL`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUrIJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcdGf.png)

Comment: Would `InTime = 'wathever' ?? "Absent"` work for your case?

Comment: @MiroslavMikus Yes I changed ti to  InTime = g.Any(e => e.ScanType == "I") ? g.Where(e => e.ScanType == "I").Min(e => e.DateAndTime).ToString("HH:mm") : "absent", and its working